# Visual Studio 2017 (15.3.1) keeps hanging/freezing

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have recently installed Visual Studio 15.3.1 Community Edition (although I suspect this affects all editions). When doing actions such as

- closing SQL `.sql` file tabs
- copying or renaming files
- other actions which I can't pinpoint

Visual Studio will freeze or hang for a few seconds or permanantly. It sometimes displays "(Not Responding)" in the title bar, but not always. This is getting really frustrating.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the Visual Studio feedback system is at fault. Turning it off solved my problem.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Navigate to `Help` > `Privacy` > `Privacy Settings`
3. Select the "No, I would not like to participate" radio button and click OK

Hopefully whatever bug is causing this issue will be fixed soon and I'll happily participate in the feedback program again!

Comment: But how will they know about this issue if you've stopped sending feedback?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Given that the feedback sender always gets freezes, there are only two possibilities.
1. The feedback is sent at least once.
2. There is a problem on sending feedback.
For each possibility, disabling "Send Feedback" setting will be a right choice.

Comment: This just fixed VS 2017 and VS 2022 on my backup dev machine.  I think installing VS 2022 turned the setting on globally for all VS instances, as I didn't have the issue with just VS 2017 installed.

Answer (score 1):

See this issue posted a lot on the MS forums.

I struggled with it for a while.  When editing XAML files, it would always freeze and hang.

Tried many solutions that didn't fixed it.  Then, I found the solution that did fix it for me.

I made two changes at the same time, so I can't say for sure which one solved it, but I can guess.

**First change**, *which probably isn't the fix*, is that [I added the registry keys from this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/set-defaults-for-enterprise-deployments?view=vs-2017).  They were missing on my system.  Page has a lot of detail, but having those keys set properly can't hurt. I noticed in Process Monitor that it was missing on the following regkey:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\CachePath
```

**Second change I made**, *the one I'm guessing solved the issue*, was deleting the 17k+ ".TRN" files inside the following directory:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights\
```

On my computer they were in something like the following:

```
C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSApplicationInsights\vstelXXX_SOMEGUID
```

Going back to check now, and after three-or-so hours of work there's another 475 files in that folder.  It's producing about four or five .TRN files a minute, all with encrypted data inside.  Not going to speculate as to the purpose of it, but I doubt it's anything good or useful.  Deleted all those, and the XAML editor in VS now works fine, or at least as well as it ever did.  No more 30+ second hangs on a modern twentysome core workstation.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent update of VS 2022, the program suddenly starts freezing (randomly) and the fix for me was to turn off `inline hints` (the thing that pops up when you double click Ctrl key).

I'm using VS for C++ so I turned it off for C++ specifically

Go to the `Tools` menu tab -> `Options`
[image: Turn Off Inline hints]